# Pass positional argument as a variable to awk

Tags: shell, awk

This is my simple script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(awk '$2 ~ /$1/ {print $0}' numeri-telefonici.txt | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

and `numeri-telefonici.txt` file is

```
00000 Alessandro
11312 Mark
```

unfortunately when I execute this script (`./script.sh Alessandro`) an empty row is print:  , but If i execute `awk '$2 ~ /Alessandro/ {print $0}' numeri-telefonici.txt | cut -d' ' -f1` I get successfully `00000`.

- How do I fix?

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts in your question, keep it up. Could you please what you are trying o achieve by script? Do you want to pass an argument to awk program and compare 2nd field of your file to it?

Answer (score 2):

`$1`, `$2` are positional parameters in the shell context that are passed to a script from command line or to a function.

In `Awk`,  they represent column designators defined by the `FS`. In your attempt, you are basically only using the `awk`'s designators, i.e. your match is doing

```
/Alessandro/ ~ 00000 
#  $2        ~   $1
```

You need to pass the positional argument to the context of `awk`, by importing them as `awk` variables using `-v`

```
awk -v re="$1" ' $2 ~ re { print $1 }'
```

Note the usage of `print $1` instead of `$0`, as your operation to later use `cut` to get the first field is unnecessary as you can get the first column value directly from `$1`